# According to Dvaita philosophy,what are the duties of Vaishnava in Vaikuntha?

Tags: philosophy, vaishnavism, dvaita

According to Dvaita philosophy, Jivatma reaches to Parmatma loka to attain moksha. However it is not clear what will be the duties of Jivatma towards the Parmatma.

My questions are:

After moksha,what are duties of Jivatma towards the Parmatma?

What happens to the Jivatmas in Vaikuntha when Parmatma leaves Vaikuntha to reincarnate on Earth?(for example Krishna reincarnated on Earth leaving his abode to fulfill his karma.Do the Jivatmas following Parmatma also reincarnate on Earth?)

Comment: Related: [What will the soul do after moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/what-will-the-soul-do-after-moksha)

Comment: @Rishabh I got partial answer. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Rishabh The answer already seems to be there. I want to delete this post and post a fresh question. Can I do that ?

Comment: If you wanna post a fresh question then you can turn this question into your fresh question instead of deleting because deleting own post is not recommended. Once I delete my one question and later asked to un-delete, so I did undelete it later.

Comment: You shouldn't add answer into the question saying [here](link). Add an answer by quoting that answer instead or close the question as Duplicate. .

Comment: The Q's are related but unless there is a definition of moksha from the dvaita perspective or an answer carrying the same, the other Q does not answer this one. This Q speaks more to sAlOkya mukti.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I am also not clear on the definition of Moksha in Dvaita philosophy. If we meet again anywhere we are bound to collapse because every world is mythya or dream like.

Comment: Vaishnavas believe that moksha is when you get to the Vaikuntha. There you serve the Lord Vishnu and participate in his lilas. That's all that you do. I explained to you earlier that Lord Krishna doesn't have karma. Did you forget? Advaitins (Advaita system of Vedanta) believe that every world is mythya and illusion, but not the Vaishnavas who believe that worlds are real (reality). When you get moksha in Vaikuntha you don't come back to this world of samsara ever again! You stay in Vaikuntha as a liberated soul eternally. I explained that at *Will I (Psycho-Physical 'I') cease to exist ...*